# Как передать тип переменной из одного метода в другого? Или как сохранить тип?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вот у нас есть метод, который проверяет являются ли элементы массива юнитами:

```
public static void SelectGroup()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedGroup.Count; i++)
    {
        Unit unit = selectedGroup[i].GetComponent(UnitType );
        if (unit != null) { };
    }
}
```

И мы хотим, что бы мы могли задавать тип искомых юнитов из другого места, допустим методом вида:

```
public static void SelectingUnitType<T>()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Собственно моя проблема была в том, что я забыл указать `where T : Unit`

Когда я всё поправил, вот такая штука у меня получилась:

```
public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Type _selectableUnitType;
 
    public static void SelectingUnitType<T>() where T : Unit
    {
        _selectableUnitType = typeof(T);
    }
 
    public static void SelectGroup()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedGroup.Count; i++)
        {
            Unit unit = selectedGroup[i].GetComponent(_selectableUnitType) as Unit;
            if (unit != null) { };
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь мы можем задавать тип выделяемых юнитов из любого места

```
Controller.SelectingUnitType<UnitType>();
```

Что касается unity и данной реализации, что бы работал `GetComponent()`, класс Unit должен быть наследником либо от Component, либо от MonoBehaviour.